# pandas read excel: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to use pandas (pd.read_excel) to import excel file to python. Yet it gives me the error "IndexError: list index out of range".

I have checked the excel file has no security lock and it's XLSX and not Strict XML Open Spreadsheet.

I can import it if I just copy all the tabs to another excel, but I just cannot import the original excel file.

Is there any reason for it? Cause I have like hundreds of excels to import and I just can't copy all the tabs for all excel files one by one.

Really thanks if anyone could help me out of it!

the code is just simple as below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)
```

And the following error message appear

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f5977f03f042> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    334     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    335         should_close = True
--> 336         io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    337     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    338         raise ValueError(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1129         self.storage_options = storage_options
   1130 
-> 1131         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
   1132 
   1133     def __fspath__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    473         """
    474         import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
--> 475         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
    476 
    477     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    389             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
    390             self.handles.handle.seek(0)
--> 391             self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
    392         elif isinstance(self.handles.handle, bytes):
    393             self.book = self.load_workbook(BytesIO(self.handles.handle))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    484         from openpyxl import load_workbook
    485 
--> 486         return load_workbook(
    487             filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
    488         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                         data_only, keep_links)
--> 317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in read(self)
    279         self.read_properties()
    280         self.read_theme()
--> 281         apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
    282         self.read_worksheets()
    283         self.parser.assign_names()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in apply_stylesheet(archive, wb)
    196 
    197     node = fromstring(src)
--> 198     stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
    199 
    200     wb._borders = IndexedList(stylesheet.borders)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101         for k in attrs:
    102             del node.attrib[k]
--> 103         return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
    104 
    105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101                 attrib[tag] = obj
    102 
--> 103         return cls(**attrib)
    104 
    105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in __init__(self, numFmts, fonts, fills, borders, cellStyleXfs, cellXfs, cellStyles, dxfs, tableStyles, colors, extLst)
     92         self.protections = self.cellXfs.prots
     93         self._normalise_numbers()
---> 94         self.named_styles = self._merge_named_styles()
     95 
     96 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in _merge_named_styles(self)
    112 
    113         for style in named_styles:
--> 114             self._expand_named_style(style)
    115 
    116         return named_styles

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in _expand_named_style(self, named_style)
    122         record
    123         """
--> 124         xf = self.cellStyleXfs[named_style.xfId]
    125         named_style.font = self.fonts[xf.fontId]
    126         named_style.fill = self.fills[xf.fillId]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\cell_style.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
    183 
    184     def __getitem__(self, idx):
--> 185         return self.xf[idx]
    186 
    187 

IndexError: list index out of range

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f5977f03f042> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    334     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    335         should_close = True
--> 336         io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    337     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    338         raise ValueError(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1129         self.storage_options = storage_options
   1130 
-> 1131         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
   1132 
   1133     def __fspath__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    473         """
    474         import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
--> 475         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
    476 
    477     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    389             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
    390             self.handles.handle.seek(0)
--> 391             self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
    392         elif isinstance(self.handles.handle, bytes):
    393             self.book = self.load_workbook(BytesIO(self.handles.handle))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    484         from openpyxl import load_workbook
    485 
--> 486         return load_workbook(
    487             filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
    488         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                         data_only, keep_links)
--> 317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in read(self)
    279         self.read_properties()
    280         self.read_theme()
--> 281         apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
    282         self.read_worksheets()
    283         self.parser.assign_names()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in apply_stylesheet(archive, wb)
    196 
    197     node = fromstring(src)
--> 198     stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
    199 
    200     wb._borders = IndexedList(stylesheet.borders)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101         for k in attrs:
    102             del node.attrib[k]
--> 103         return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
    104 
    105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101                 attrib[tag] = obj
    102 
--> 103         return cls(**attrib)
    104 
    105 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in __init__(self, numFmts, fonts, fills, borders, cellStyleXfs, cellXfs, cellStyles, dxfs, tableStyles, colors, extLst)
     92         self.protections = self.cellXfs.prots
     93         self._normalise_numbers()
---> 94         self.named_styles = self._merge_named_styles()
     95 
     96 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in _merge_named_styles(self)
    112 
    113         for style in named_styles:
--> 114             self._expand_named_style(style)
    115 
    116         return named_styles

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in _expand_named_style(self, named_style)
    122         record
    123         """
--> 124         xf = self.cellStyleXfs[named_style.xfId]
    125         named_style.font = self.fonts[xf.fontId]
    126         named_style.fill = self.fills[xf.fillId]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\cell_style.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
    183 
    184     def __getitem__(self, idx):
--> 185         return self.xf[idx]
    186 
    187 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

[excel file screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuvCr.png)

Comment: How can we possibly offer you any help without seeing the code, and the exact traceback?  *Is there any reason for it?*  Yes, you have made a mistake.

Comment: paste ur code for better understanding

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your excel files?

Comment: I have added the code I have and the error message. I use pandas to read excel files a lot, but just for this excel file, I am not sure why pandas couldn't read it.

Comment: For anyone from the future reading this, it is apparently sometimes fixed by copying all data to a new xlsx file and saving, which may or may not be a viable workaround for you: https://github.com/OpenDataServices/flatten-tool/issues/331

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the Indexerror: list index out of range error when you try and access an item using a value that is out of the index range of the list and does not exist.

any way ,
Make sure you have the right type of Excel spreadsheets . I had the same Probleme and realized that I had saved it as a Strict XML Open Spreadsheet which still had the .xlsx extension.

Comment: How do you check if the excel file is actually Strict XML Open Spreadsheet?